# Get Azure AD AuditLogs using powershell cmd-let/REST API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to get info about changes made on Directory roles (for example Global Administrator) I need details like, username - A) user who made a change, B) timestamp, C) action - add a user to a group or remove, D) name of the group to which user has been added. I updated AD module on Azure portal, now I have AzureADPreview, and I am using cmd-let --> `Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs`. And as an output I can get only: A) B) and C). I checked all "Id" from the output but I didn't find Directory Roles IDs. Is there a method for catching this info --> (D) using mentioned PowerShell command? below, the command I used:

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDateTime gt 2019-08-25" | where-object activitydisplayname -eq "Add member to group" | fl *
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDateTime gt 2019-09-01" | where-object activitydisplayname -eq "remove member from group"
```

UPDATE:

I used Rest API in order to catch the needed information:

```
$request = "https://graph.windows.net/xxx.com/activities/audit?api-version=beta"

$authHeader = @{  
'Content-Type'='application/json'  
'Accept'='application/json'  
'Authorization'= ("Bearer $personalToken")  
}  

$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $authHeader  
$output.value
```

And in the output still, don't see info about the group to which the user has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the name of the group is not returned.

But the Object ID of the group will be shown in the result.

[image: Azure AD log]

Use `Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId {Object ID}` to get its name information.

Comment: I have corrected command, now I have --> Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDateTime gt 2019-08-25" | where-object activitydisplayname -eq "Add member to role". I can Find info about group, but Your hint is ok, thanks, we can find in the output group ID.